# PL/SQL Error With Nested IF statements

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Apex 4.2

I have the following pl/sql code block below but whenever I run it in APex, I keep getting the error:

ORA-06550: line 35, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

```
DECLARE
   show_changes BOOLEAN;
   l_exists INTEGER;

BEGIN

Select count(*) into l_exists
From dba_role_privs
where grantee = upper(:APP_USER) and
(granted_role = 'SURVEY_JOB_SUID' or granted_role = 'SURVEY_SUID');

IF l_exists = 0 THEN            /* unauthorized */
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL  AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) THEN   
           show_changes := TRUE;
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) THEN
      show_changes := TRUE;
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NOT NULL) THEN
          show_changes := FALSE;    
END IF;
ELSE                          /* authorized */  
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL  AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) THEN   
           show_changes := TRUE;
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) THEN
      show_changes := TRUE;
   IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NOT NULL) THEN
      show_changes := TRUE;

END IF;
Return show_changes;
END;
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the wrong syntax of `IF`-conditional selection statement. Please have a look to [PL/SQL Control Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/controlstatements.htm).

Answer (score 3):

An `IF` always has to be paired with an `END IF` and the `ELSE` comes before the `END IF`.  If you want to have three separate `IF` statements in each of two branches in your outer `IF`, you'd want something like

```
IF l_exists = 0
THEN
  IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL  AND 
    (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) 
  THEN   
           show_changes := TRUE;
  END IF;
  IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
     (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) 
  THEN
      show_changes := TRUE;
  END IF;
  IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
     (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NOT NULL) 
  THEN
          show_changes := FALSE;    
  END IF;
ELSE
  <<repeat the pattern>>
END IF;
```

My guess, however, is that you really don't want to have three separate `IF` statements in each branch.  My guess is that you want a single `IF` statement with an `ELSIF`

```
IF l_exists = 0
THEN
  IF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
    (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) 
  THEN   
           show_changes := TRUE;
  ELSIF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
       (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NULL) 
  THEN
      show_changes := TRUE;
  ELSIF :P32_SURVEY_JOB_REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
       (:P32_SUBMISSION_DATE IS NOT NULL     AND :P32_LOCK_DATE IS NOT NULL) 
  THEN
          show_changes := FALSE;    
  END IF;
ELSE
  <<repeat the pattern>>
END IF;
```